# Showing Datepicker's chosen date in red font and hiding the text in p element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to have datepicker (localized in Finnish language), which allows to choose date between 1/1/1996 and 31/12/2015. When the user has chosen the date, the chosen date is shown in `p` element. The `p` has in the beginning text, which says:"The date is not chosen yet". When the date is chosen from Datepicker, this text disappears, and the chosen date is shown in red font in this same `p` element. So...

1. The Datepicker works fine so far, but how could I change the last date in the calender to be 31.12.2015, instead of 31.1.2015? I tried to check example from here, but it does not work out perfectly:https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max
2. How could I make the text in `p` disappear(hide) when the date has been chosen and replace it with the chosen date, which has red font?

Here is my code so far.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Populate alternate field</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="finnish.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      altField: "#alternate",
      altFormat: "DD, d MM, yy",
      minDate: (new Date(1996, 1-1, 1)),
      maxDate: (new Date(2015, 12-12, 31))
    });

  $.datepicker.setDefaults(
  $.extend(
    {'dateFormat':'dd-mm-yy'},
    $.datepicker.regional['fi']
  )
);
  } );

//I should work on this, but how?
$( "#datepicker" ).on( "click", function() {
hide();
});


  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="text">The date is not chosen yet<input type="text" id="datepicker">&nbsp;<input type="text" id="alternate" size="30"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this JQuery:

```
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: "DD, d MM, yy",
      minDate: (new Date(1996, 1-1, 1)),
      maxDate: (new Date(2015, 12-1, 31)),
      onSelect: function(){
        var selected = $(this).val();
        $("#result").html(selected).css('color', 'red');
        }
    });
  } );
```

And the HTML body:

```
<p id="result">The date is not chosen yet</p>&nbsp;
Select date here:<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Comment: This works, but now I have problems with localizing. When I try to localize it, it does not work anymore.I don't know how to localize it so that ti works.